# How to create events for objects in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, events

I'm trying to create several objects and add them into an array which I can do but then I would like to have one event for all the objects. For example I have 50 picture boxes in an array that are created dynamically and I need to get the picture from the one I click. How do I go about doing this without making 50 seperate events?

Answer (score 7):

You hook up an event handler to `Click` event of each `PictureBox`.  Use the `sender` argument to obtain a reference to the specific `PictureBox` that was clicked (that's what `sender` is there for if you didn't know; whichever object raised the event will get passed to the handler as the `sender` parameter).

```
private void HookUpEventHandlers()
{
    var someListOfPicBoxes = GetPicBoxList();
    foreach(var p in someListOfPicBoxes)
    {
        p.Click += p_Click;
    }
}

private void p_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this is the PictureBox that was clicked
    var pb = (PictureBox)sender;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response, I have used what you have here and it is compiling fine but the event isn't being reached for some reason. I added in a message box to test and nothing appears when I click a box. This is how the boxes are created if it helps.

Comment: @Mike: Your example does not show that you are actually hooking up the event, i.e., `p.Click += p_Click;`

Answer (score 0):

You create one event handler and add it to each of the items that you create:

Add the items:

```
        for (int nI = 0; nI < 50; nI++)
        {
            PictureBox oBox;

            oBox = new PictureBox();
            oBox.Click += pictureBox_Click;

            // Add to your array
        }
```

Add the eventhandler:

```
    private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get a local reference to the box that was clicked
        PictureBox oBox = sender as PictureBox;

    }
```

Comment: Is there difference with Ed S.'s answer?